# how to read all the files under a directory in s3 using spark df?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, bigdata

I have 490 JSON files in this pattern 657438009821376.json all different numbers for different files.

can I use
'''val input = spark.read.option("header", true).json("/path/to/data/[0-9]*.json")'''

I need to read all the 490 files into a single DF

Comment: I need to grab all the files using the last digit of the JSON file. So, can i use this ____________________[0-9]*.json

Answer (score 0):

You provide as a source either file path or directory path. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html

There are no options to filter out specific files from before actually loading them. Loading them you can map their source filename & filter out unnecessary files, but I would no suggest doing that

I suggest you can do it in few steps:

- List all matching files from s3 bucket with boto3 client, smth like that

```
import boto
import boto.s3
import re

pattern = re.compile("your_regexp_pattern")

bucket = boto.s3.connect_to_region('eu-central-1').get_bucket("BUCKET_NAME")
files = bucket.list("","/path/to-dir")
filteredFiles = filter(lambda filename: pattern.match(filename), files)
```

- Provide list of files to the spark read as json from s3

```
your_schema_class = StructType() \
    .add("first_name", StringType()) \
    .add("last_name", StringType())

# From step 1:
# files = ["s3://1.json", "s3://2.json"]
df = spark.read.json(files, your_schema_class)
df.show()
```